# maximum number of locations in Google Static Maps API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-maps

I understand there is a limit to the number of requests per day using the geocoding API. Here I'm keen to build a static rendered map of several thousand positions. Obviously this would necessitate using some form of caching. So here are two questions:

1. How to cache the image in a smart fashion. Or is this necessary. In fact I just saw this.

"Use of the Google Static Maps API is subject to a query limit of 1000 unique (different) image requests per viewer per day. Since this restriction is a quota per viewer, most developers should not need to worry about exceeding their quota. However, note that we enforce an additional request rate limit to prevent abuse of the service. Requests of identical images, in general, do not count towards this limit beyond the original request."

1. Is there a limit to the length of the string I can send to googleapis.com? I.e. is 1000 places going to be unhandlable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you observe, the quota is per client - so each of your users can fetch up to 1000 static maps per day. There's no limit on how many static maps your app can instruct your users' browsers to fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is enforced by the limit on the length of a URL. This varies between browsers; but there is also a limit in the API:

> Static Map URLs are restricted to 2048 characters in size.

1000 points will need a thousand instances of a geographic coordinate which will probably be up to 20 characters long (`51.12345,-134.12345`) so you won't be able to accommodate that. It may be worth considering why you want that many markers on a map: it's highly likely to be unintelligible.

Regarding caching: Google cache the images and different clients requesting the same image only counts once.

Comment: Thanks. As for usage I wanted to give an overall visual identifier of the number of certain entities in one country in one go hence the vast number of "spots". So hence doing a clustering. Hmm, I wonder if the JS API would work for this...Ive not looked as yet, but thats a bit overkill.

Comment: You could do server-side clustering and put a reduced number of numbered custom icons in a Static Map. But in order to expand the clusters you're looking at a dynamic map.

Comment: rats, I was rather hoping I could use the Static Maps. Thanks